# How to check if given page is a ZERO_PAGE in a kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mmu, rhel5, kbuild

I am writing a kernel module, where, inside a function I need to check if passed
`struct page*` maps to `ZERO_PAGE` or not.
I came up with following code to check the condition.

```
foo (struct page *pp, ..) {
     if(pp == ZERO_PAGE(0)) {
          //say, prefault the page.
     }
}
```

When I try to compile this , I get following warning message:

```
WARNING: "phys_base" [<path_to_'.ko'] undefined!
```

when I try to 'insmod'  the '.ko' , It gives error "Unknown symbol".and  prints
"Unknown symbol phys_base" in log buffer.
My Makefile:

```
obj-m :=zero_page.o

KDIR=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

all:
        make -C $(KDIR) M=`pwd` modules
```

The kernel version for which I am writing the module:
**2.6.18-398.el5 (rhel 5.11)**
I tried to find some other 'interfaces' inside kernel to check if page is ZERO_PAGE, but no luck.
Can some tell me how to get rid of this error.OR any other way to check this condition ?

NOTE: I came across this kernelnewbie [thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=kernelnewbies@kernelnewbies.org&q=subject:%22%5C%5Bkernel%5C%5Dwhich%20the%20file%20define%20the%20variable%20of%20%5C%22phys_base%5C%22%5C%3F%22&o=newest&f=1) which addressed the same issue. included `<asm/pgtable.h>` but no help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a fix for this.
After browsing some kernel code , I found out , for ZERO_PAGE address_space ptr is NULL.
Hence fix looks something like this :

```
if(page->mapping == NULL) {
   // Its a ZERO_PAGE.
}
```

Thank you.